# Could a smart compiler do all the things std::move does without it being part of the language?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move

This is a bit theoretical question, but although I have some basic understanding of the std::move Im still not certain if it provides some additional functionality to the language that theoretically couldnt be achieved with supersmart compilers. I know that code like :

```
{
  std::string s1="STL";
  std::string s2(std::move(s1));
  std::cout << s1 <<std::endl;
}
```

is a new semantic behavior not just performance sugar. :D But tbh I guess nobody will use var x after doing std::move(x).
Also for movable only data (std::unique_ptr<>, std::thread) couldnt compiler automatically do the move construction and clearing of the old variable if type is declared movable?
Again this would mean that more code would be generated behind programmers back(for example now you can count cpyctor and movector calls, with automagic std::moving you couldnt do that ).

Comment: I don't like implicit destructive operations.

Comment: isnt moving transparent to rest of the program? I would understand that you dont like RAII being replaced with something that could fire destructors at any place after last usage of s2. But automove wouldnt do that, it would just basically do memcopy for data that has sizeof T/size_of_all_memory_T_handles ratio low.

Comment: And what happens to the *source* of the move? It's effectively destroyed. And I wasn't notified.

Comment: it would only happen if you dont use it anymore... in dreamland ofc, see the DeadMG answer to see that it cant be determined.

Comment: The above code, being within brackets and with no external references other than cout, is easily analyzed in full detail by a compiler of moderate sophistication, and many things could be done by the compiler.  But in the more general case you can't count on a compiler being able to work out the data flows.

Comment: Btw, `std::unique_ptr<int> f(){ auto p = make_unique<int>(42); return p; }` *will* automatically move `p`, since it can never be used again.

Comment: not the point but make_unique is not standard... Will be though one day.. Herb promised. :D

Comment: There's a reason I didn't qualify it. ;)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `std::unique_ptr<int> f(){ auto p = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)); return p; }` is nearly the same (unless `int`'s constructor throws), so it really isn't to the point.  :p

Answer (score 7):

No.

> But tbh I guess nobody will use var x after doing std::move(x)

Absolutely not guaranteed. In fact, a decent part of the reason why `std::move(x)` is *not* automatically usable by the compiler is because, well, it can't be decided automatically whether or not you intend this. It's explicitly well-defined behaviour.

Also, removing rvalue references would imply that the compiler can automagically write all the move constructors for you. This is definitely not true. D has a similar scheme, but it's a complete failure, because there are numerous useful situations in which the compiler-generated "move constructor" won't work correctly, but you can't change it.

It would also prevent perfect forwarding, which has other uses.

The Committee make many stupid mistakes, but rvalue references is not one of them.

Edit:

Consider something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> x = make_unique<int>();
    some_func_that_takes_ownership(x);
    int input = 0;
    std::cin >> input;
    if (input == 0)
        some_other_func(x);
}
```

Owch. Now what? You can't magic the value of "input" to be known at compile-time. This is doubly a problem if the bodies of `some_other_func` and `some_func_that_takes_ownership` are unknown. This is Halting Problem- you can't prove that `x` is or is not used after `some_func_that_takes_ownership`.

D fails. I promised an example. Basically, in D, "move" is "binary copy and don't destruct the old". Unfortunately, consider a class with, say, a pointer to itself- something you will find in most string classes, most node-based containers, in designs for `std::function`, `boost::variant`, and lots of other similar handy value types. The pointer to the internal buffer will be copied but oh noes! points to the old buffer, not the new one. Old buffer is deallocated - GG your program.

Comment: Rgarding using x: I thing it is a crappy programming practice, can you provide me with example where is this a good idea. Regarding detecting it automatically can you provide some source for that claim.

Comment: Automatic detection is solving the Halting Problem, which is impossible in the general case.

Comment: Sorry for harassing :)  you but can I get source for claim that auto detection is "equivalent" to HP. I know of HP so no need to link to provide source for that. Also reference for D move fails would be nice.

Comment: Regarding you example: compiler pessimizes and doesnt automove x and that is it.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes, what you're looking for is [alias analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_analysis). Coupled with [termination analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termination_analysis), you could probably prove that a value is uniquely referenced for all practical programs. People need to remember that the domain for the Halting Problem is *all possible programs*. That's a hell of a tall order! Humans don't write all possible programs, though, so it's a bit of a cop-out to not try to do something because of the Halting Problem.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that this analysis takes *effort*, and lots of it. The benefits do not outweigh the costs at this time, especially for a language like C++ where we're already expected to be explicit about behavior anyway.

Comment: Except pessimizations make your program run slower. And in this case, can also make it much less correct. Remember, movable types depend on rvalue references for correctness, not just speed. You're basically eliminating the advantages of rvalue references.

Comment: @DeadMG D example seems easily detectable by compiler, again by pessimization, if I cant prove it is safe to memcpy I wont. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Except, again, you're pessimizing away *all the benefits*. Proving that it's safe to memcpy non-trivial classes is, well, probably akin to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: Nope it isnt... every type that is tagged by compiler as memcopyable (compiler devs need to do that) and every collection (class or struct) of those types is memcpyable. Ofc works recursively so if struct X and Y are memcpyable class that is {int a; double b; X x; Y y;} is memcpyable

Comment: Except those types don't have significant move semantics. In order to try and automate rvalue references, you've cut every reason to have it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "what move does". To satisfy your curiosity, I think what you're looking to be told about the existence of [**Uniqueness Type Systems**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_typing) and [**Linear Type Systems**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_type_system).

These are types systems that enforce, at compile-time (in the type system), that a value only be referenced by one location, or that no new references be made. `std::unique_ptr` is the best approximation C++ can provide, given its rather weak type system.

Let's say we had a new storage-class specifier called `uniqueref`. This is like `const`, and specifies that the value has a single unique reference; nobody else has the value. It would enable this:

```
int main()
{
    int* uniqueref x(new int); // only x has this reference

    // unique type feature: error, would no longer be unique
    auto y = x; 

    // linear type feature: okay, x not longer usable, z is now the unique owner
    auto z = uniquemove(x);

    // linear type feature: error: x is no longer usable
    *x = 5;
}
```

(Also interesting to note the immense optimizations that can be taking, knowing a pointer value is really truly only referenced through that pointer. It's a bit like C99's `restrict` in that aspect.)

In terms of what you're asking, since we can now say that a type is uniquely referenced, we can guarantee that it's safe to move. That said, move operates are ultimately user-defined, and can do all sorts of weird stuff if desired, so implicitly doing this is a bad idea in current C++ anyway.

Everything above is obviously not formally thought-out and specified, but should give you an idea of what such a type system might look like. More generally, you probably want an [**Effect Type System**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system).

But yes, these ideas do exist and are formally researched. C++ is just too established to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this the way you suggest is a lot more complicated than necessary:

```
std::string s1="STL";
std::string s2(s1);
std::cout << s1 <<std::endl;
```

In this case, it is fairly sure that a copy is meant. But if you drop the last line, `s1` essentially ends its lifetime after the construction of `s2`.

In a reference counted implementation, the copy constructor for `std::string` will only increment the reference counter, while the destructor will decrement and delete if it becomes zero.

So the sequence is

1. (inlined `std::string::string(char const *)`)

   1. determine string length
   2. allocate memory
   3. copy string
   4. initialize reference counter to 1
   5. initialize pointer in string object
2. (inlined `std::string::string(std::string const &)`)

   1. increment reference counter
   2. copy pointer to string representation

Now the compiler can flatten that, simply initialize the reference counter to 2 and store the pointer twice. Common Subexpression Elimination then finds out that `s1` and `s2` keep the same pointer value, and merges them into one.

In short, the only difference in generated code should be that the reference counter is initialized to 2.