# Do C++ coders usually do moves explicitly or do they just rely on the compiler to do it?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

We have this in some function:

```
BigClass big;
// prepare big somehow
OtherClass foo(std::move(big), maybe, other, params);
// know that we won't be using "big" after this.
```

Would most C++ coders these days actually put the move there to guarantee a move?

Comment: The only two cases where a named lvalue might be moved from are `return identifer;` and `throw identifier`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your particular piece of code, either you move directly or there won't be a move at all. The compiler will never move out of an *lvalue* (that is not *eXpiring*).

Comment: Even if it's just a move constructor? (note the "maybe" other params) And even if the compiler sees that the big is not being used anywhere afterward?

Comment: Yep.  Lifetime guarantees are important.  Even move elision of xvalues is somewhat dangerous (in that it can change the order that things are destroyed) -- doing so every time a variable isn't used would probably break a lot of code.

Comment: @user2015453: Related to your chain of thought (automatic moves): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111040/could-a-smart-compiler-do-all-the-things-stdmove-does-without-it-being-part-of

Comment: @user2015453: Things could be much more complicated than this. It might be that `big` is not used anywhere else after the function call, but that there is some other alias (pointer/reference)... The move of an xvalue is *safe* in the sense that any use of the object through an alias would be UB, but in this case the object is still alive until the end of the scope, not just this line. The language must be conservative, more so when the user has the option of requesting the move manually if wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the `std::move` in there for there to be a move, because otherwise there won't be.  :)

An alternative is:

```
auto MakeBig = [&]()->BigClass {
  BigClass big;
  //prepare big somehow
  return big; // must be a `move`, if not elided!
};

OtherClass foo(MakeBig(), maybe, other, params);
```

or, if you aren't faint of heart:

```
OtherClass foo([&]()->BigClass {
  BigClass big;
  //prepare big somehow
  return big; // must be a `move`, if not elided!
}(), maybe, other, params);
```

where we wrap the creation of `big` up into a lambda, and then defer the creation.  This doesn't always work, mind you.

An advantage of this pattern is that the move can be elided if `foo` takes its first argument by value, and taking by value is now the right way to do it for a `move` able class that `OtherClass` will be making a copy of anyhow.  If it doesn't take its first argument by value, the temporary created for constructing `foo` can still be elided into, so only one move (between the temporary, and `foo`) will occur.

Comment: A disadvantage of this pattern is that it's ugly ;-) - Two line's worth of extra punctuation, pointless indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 sometimes the compiler will do moves for you (R-Value references), but if you want to explicitly move a big object then yes you should explicitly 'move' it using

```
std::move
```

[More information](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)