# Why won't it move?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

This may be compiler dependent (using VS2010), or not, but why does the following operation not invoke the expected move behavior:

```
LargeObject x;
x = SomeFunc(x);
```

I have defined the function as the pair

```
LargeObject SomeFunc(const LargeObject& ob)
{
    LargeObject newOb;
    // perform operation on new object using old object
    return newOb;
}

LargeObject SomeFunc(LargeObject&& ob)
{
    // change object directly...
    return std::move(ob);
}
```

I explicitly need to write

```
x = SomeFunc(std::move(x));
```

to make it happen, and I don't like that...

EDIT: The first function, making use of the const-ref, is because I also need to do things like

```
LargeObject x;
LargeObject y = SomeFunc(x);
```

Comment: You prefer to have moves occur implicitly?

Comment: @Fernandes, yes to me it seems obvious I don't need `x` anymore later in my code...

Comment: I see absolutely zero difference between `SomeFunc(x)` in the first example and `SomeFunc(x)` in the last example. I am really curious how you expect them to behave differently.

Comment: Why don't you do `x = SomeFunc(LargeObject());`?

Comment: @JesseGood, in this particular case (code snippet) that is useful, but this comes from a whole different situation where `x` is already modified.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111040/could-a-smart-compiler-do-all-the-things-stdmove-does-without-it-being-part-of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is an lvalue, so when you do:

```
x = SomeFunc(x);
```

The overload accepting an lvalue reference to `const` is chosen, because rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues. If you want your second overload to be chosen, you have to turn `x` into an rvalue somehow. This is what `std::move` does.

> ... and I don't like that...

I believe you would like it even less if passing an object to a function implicitly meant moving it!

Whether a move is performed or not depends on how *you* instruct the compiler. First of all, in the general case the compiler alone won't (and **cannot**) perform semantic analysis on your code to determine whether or not you will need `x` after the call to `SomeFunc(x)`.

Moreover, it would be really weird if the following two instructions caused a different behavior when passing arguments:

```
SomeFunc(x);         // Does not move
x = SomeFunc(x);     // Moves!?
```

Comment: Yea, true that. But I think the compiler should be more intelligent in this case and pass `x` as an rvalue. But your explanation is reasonable.

Comment: @demorge: Nonono, the compiler should *not* do that, it would mean that movement is no more triggered by the value category of your object (rvalues vs lvalues), but by the future usage of your object in your code. And that could change (what if you add an instruction using `x` 1000 lines below?) Believe me, you do not want the compiler to move unless you have an rvalue. And if you have an lvalue to begin with, you have to explicitly turn it into an rvalue by telling the compiler "ok, I am really aware of what I am doing, I am moving away from this object".

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason, why compiler should call a move ctor here. Move-ctor is assured, that the object passed as a parameter won't be used no more, while in your case x is a local variable and *can* be used (bah, it *is* used in the following assignment operation, which can be overloaded etc.). If you call explicitly:

```
x = SomeFunc(std::move(x));
```

You risk using x damaged by move operation further (compiler wouldn't care, that you assign the result to the same variable again).

Try:

```
LargeObject ReturnsLargeObject()
{
    LargeObject x;
    return x;
}

SomeFunc(ReturnsLargeObject());
```

Your move ctor should be called in this situation.